# OpenGLES Issues freeing variable that then needs returning

Tags: memory-management, opengl-es, free, opengl-es-2.0

I've implemented Bill Dudney's .Obj [model loader](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) in an OpenGL project of mine and am currently having massive memory leaks!

Using instruments, I've managed to narrow it down to the function below. And I think it's something to do with ptr never being freed, but I still need to return ptr at the end of the function.

```
const void * TextureCoordBytes(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value, GLuint *size)
{
// extract the count
GLuint count = ((GLuint *)value)[0];
void *ptr = NULL;
if(1 == count)
{ // a 1D texture
    ptr = CFAllocatorAllocate(allocator, sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[0] = ((TextureCoord1D *)value)->u;
    *size = sizeof(GLfloat);
}
else if(2 == count)
{ // a 2D texture
    ptr = CFAllocatorAllocate(allocator, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[0] = ((TextureCoord2D *)value)->u;
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[1] = ((TextureCoord2D *)value)->v;
    *size = 2 * sizeof(GLfloat);
}
else if(3 == count)
{ // a 3D texture
    ptr = CFAllocatorAllocate(allocator, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[0] = ((TextureCoord3D *)value)->u;
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[1] = ((TextureCoord3D *)value)->v;
    ((GLfloat*)ptr)[2] = ((TextureCoord3D *)value)->w;
    *size = 3 * sizeof(GLfloat);
}
return ptr;
}
```

Does anybody know of something I'm missing here or of a way I can use `free(ptr);` and still `return ptr;` after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first return ptr, use the allocated data, than free it. The consumer of returned ptr-s should handle freeing when no longer needed or at app exit.